# How complex of an operation is changing a file name?

Tags: java

I'm looking for ways to mark a file from a java application(to tell my program that the file is being used). I am thinking of adding some type of a token to the beginning of a file name, and I'm wondering if this is too slow of a process. Keep in mind that this might be happening multiple times in one second, so the time efficiency is important.

Comment: Renaming a file is very fast.

Comment: Did you even tried to rename a file ? Then tried to rename 100 files ? This is easy to check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is really fast, because the file doesn't even change. Your file system will not read or write to the file at all, the name is stored somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

An easy file renaming test gives the following results:

```
Renaming a file 10 times with Java takes 44 ms.
Renaming a file 100 times with Java takes 70 ms.
Renaming a file 1000 times with Java takes 397 ms.
Renaming a file 10000 times with Java takes 1339 ms.
Renaming a file 100000 times with Java takes 8452 ms.
```

Assuming you have `/Users/UserName/test/` folder created, try:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        testRename(10);
        testRename(100);
        testRename(1000);
        testRename(10000);
        testRename(100000);
    }

    public static void testRename(int times) throws IOException {
        String folderPath = "/Users/UserName/test/";

        File targetFile = new File(folderPath + "0");
        targetFile.createNewFile();

        long tic = System.nanoTime();
        Path path;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            String name = String.valueOf(i);
            path = Paths.get(folderPath + name);
            Files.move(path, path.resolveSibling(String.valueOf(i + 1)));
        }
        long tac = System.nanoTime();
        long result = (tac - tic) / 1000 / 1000;

        new File(folderPath + times).delete();

        System.out.println(String.format("Renaming a file %d times with Java takes %d ms.", times, result));
    }
}
```